# The property "for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\{t_n\}$ with $t_n \to 0$ such that $|f_n(t_n)| \leq \epsilon$."

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence of real-valued functions $f_n$ that converge to a function $f$.

I have the following result:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a sequence $\{t_n\}$ (monotonically decreasing) with $t_n \to 0$ such that $|f_n(t_n)| \leq \epsilon$.

Is there some meaning or use for this statement? Or is this property called something? If the $f_n$ were continuous and independent of $n$ this would mean that $f(0) = 0$. Is there something similiar that can be said in the general case?

Comment: For which $n$ holds $|f_n(t_n)|\leq\epsilon$?

Comment: @Wauzl for all $n$

Comment: Possibly something I wrote about in this [20 May 2000 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=243385) will be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really think, that this condition does a lot. Consider for example $f_k(x) = (1-x)^k - 1$. We can see that this we get pointwise (improper for $x>0$) convergence to
$$
f_k(x) \to f(x) = \begin{cases}
\infty & x<0\\
0 & x=0 \\
-1& 0<x<2\end{cases}
$$
and indefinite divergence for $x\geq 2$. The most irregular behaviour at the origin, that you can imagine. Still your condition holds, since you can always choose the constant sequence $t_k\equiv 0$ and $f_k(t_k)\equiv 0$. The $t_k$ are monotonically (but not strictly) decreasing. But $t_k= e^{-k}$ is strictly decreasing, but still $f_k(t_{k+k_0})\to 0$ for every $k_0\in\mathbb N$.

Consider, for example $f_k(x) = \frac1{1+k^2 x^2} - 1/2$. It converges to $f(x)=-1/2$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1/2$ pointwise. But your condition still holds, because for every $\epsilon$ we can take the sequence $t_k = 1/k$, which is monotonically decreasing and it holds $f_k(t_k) = 0$ for all $k$.